# transferir um texto separadamente um texto encontrado dentro de um textbox

Tags: array, vb.net, visual-basic-6

Pegar um determinado texto dentro de um outro textbox ou richtextbox tanto faz quando houver um incidência de texto detalhado ex: "text": tirar das aspas duplas quando a proxima sentença for encontrada e levar para um campo textbox separado

Escrevi 
este código ele consegue selecionar o texto que estou buscando dentro de um textbox.

Coloquei uma imagem abaixo para explicar melhor o que preciso
[image: EXEMPLO]

```
 Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim strTexto As String
        strTexto = TextBox3.Text

        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text


        While i < RichTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(strTexto)
            RichTextBox1.Find(strTexto, i, RichTextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
            RichTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Orange
            i = RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(strTexto, i) + 1

            txt_resultado.Text = i.ToString
        End While

    End Sub
```

Comment: Parabéns pelo capricho na pergunta, mas não entendi bem o que quer. Qual a dúvida? O que está dando errado? Defina melhor "quando houver um incidência de texto detalhado ex: "text": tirar das aspas duplas quando a proxima sentença for encontrada"

Comment: Maniero , eu preciso pegar o texto que vem em seguida de cada item "text": dentro das aspas porque eu só quero o conteúdo que está dentro das aspas duplas que é  o conteúdo encontrado dentro da receita federal , quando eu fizer isso vou disponibilizar esse projeto a toda comunidade pois várias e várias pessoas precisam disso .

Comment: Clica na imagem que os detalhes do que eu preciso estão dentro do textbox superior como exemplo, mais não estão sendo capturados eu dei um control + c e control + v

Comment: É **garantido** que sempre virá dois pontos depois e logo em seguida o texto entre aspas e que não pode ter aspas dentro dele?

Comment: Então o texto sempre vem formatado veja nesse site que eu vou te mandar ele sempre vem do mesmo jeito , segue o link https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/33000167000101

Comment: Acho que entendi, se eu tiver tempo vejo se dá para responder.

Comment: Fico agradecido pelo seu tempo e sua ajuda .

Comment: Preciso fazer exatamente isso só que no VB
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEP6cOrojTs

Comment: Um amigo resolveu pra mim em JSON , Marcio Fessini professor .
Obrigado pela atenção Maniero